# Replace x with -1 in $ y' = \frac 32({1+x^\frac 23})^\frac 12 \ ({\frac 23 x^\frac {-1}3}) $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **Question:**
>
> Find an equation of the tangent line to the given curve at the given point
>   $
>  y = ({1+x^\frac 23})^\frac 32 \ 
> $
>   at $ x = -1$

This gives the slope:

> $  y' = \frac 32({1+x^\frac 23})^\frac 12 \ ({\frac 23 x^\frac {-1}3}) $

and now I'm stuck. How do I replace $x$ with $-1$ when they have a square root?

The slope is supposed to be equal to $\sqrt{2} 
$ but I just can't see it.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate $(-1)^{2/3}$?  That's a small, but crucial, step in evaluating $y'$ when $x = 1$.

Comment: Yeah there's the problem, I don't know how. $i^2 = -1$ is the only thing I can think of. Please enlighten me.

Comment: $(-1)^{2/3}$ can be computed in either of two ways, either as $\sqrt[3]{(-1)^2}$ or as $(\sqrt[3]{-1})^2$.

Comment: Where is the square root? I see only cubics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually one simply finds $f'(x)$ and sets $x = a$. In this case $a = -1$. However, negative numbers raised to fractional powers are, in general, ill-defined and one needs to adopt a particular conventions. Since this a calculus problem, the standard conventions is to treat $(-1)^{2/3}$ as $1$ and $(-1)^{1/3}$ as $-1$. Just use your calculator to check the convention or ask your instructor.

Comment: I must have missed those pages because I don't remember seeing that convention.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**  Where you see  $x$ on the $RHS$ put a $-1$ and evaluate.

e.g. if $f'(x) = x+1$ at $x = -1$ we get $f'(-1) = -1+1 = 0$

For your specific case: $f'(-1) = \frac{3}{2}(1+(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}})^\frac{1}{2}\times(\frac{2}{3}(-1)^{\frac{-1}{3}} = \sqrt{2}$